# Jquery scroll slowly to h1 tag minus 100 pixels on page load

Tags: jquery, scroll, pageload

I have a number of pages where I want the user to be aware there is content above the h1 tag (a search box) but not have to scroll past it every time to get to the content.

I know how to do a clickable link that will fire JQuery to scroll the page down to a specific id but I can't seem to find any way to:
1) scroll down on page load.
2) scroll to h1 rather than an element id.

Is it possible?

Cheers

Comment: Post relevant jQuery, HTML, and CSS in a [mcve], please.

Comment: *`1) scroll down on page load`* *down* where?? *`2) scroll to h1 rather than an element id`* what have you tried so far?

Comment: Appreciate your comments but didn't realise something this basic needed code posted. Ish's answer below was exactly what I was looking for with a very slight edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('h1:first').offset().top
    }, 800, function() {
    });
});
```

Comment: Beautiful! I changed 'top' to 'top-100' which then shows some content above the h1 so the user is clear there is content there. Ish you are a star!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this, if you don't want to animate scroll:
https://jsfiddle.net/q3nzk3d4/1/

```
 $(document).ready(function() 
{
        $('html, body').scrollTop($('h1:first').offset().top);
})
```

Comment: Thanks mirushaki, this is 90% there but I want the user to be aware of the search box so something like, load, wait half a second, animated scroll down to h1 minus 100px (ie show 100px of the page above the h1 tag so it is clear that there is content above)